# A basic question on linear maps in inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose we have a linear map $S:V \to V$ with the property that $\langle Sv,v\rangle =0$ for all $v \in V$. Then is it true that $\langle Su,v \rangle =\langle Sv,u\rangle$ for any $u,v \in V$?

Answer (score 1):

What do you get if you expand out
$
 \langle S(u+v),(u+v) \rangle
$?

Comment: no it gives one is the negative of the other.

Comment: Indeed! So really, what things boil down to is this: can you think of an anti-symmetric matrix that isn't symmetric?